# Crossdomain settings in Google Chrome

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, cross-domain

I'm wondering, in IE & Firefox you're able to setup the browser, to allow
cross-domain calls.

I can't find any option in chrome for that (actually, there are in general not too much options at all...)

are there any about:config like things?

Kind Regards

--Andy

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. Sorry.

Chrome and Firefox, however do support cross-domain requests via the [W3C CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/2008/WD-access-control-20080912/) spec (Cross Origin resource sharing) however the remote host has to enable it.  If the remote host supports it explicitly then you don't have to make any changes to your XMLHttpRequest to be able to fetch the content.

Comment: Could you give some example please?

Comment: Yeah, examples would be great.

Answer (score 21):

**This answer was correct when written, but is longer correct, the switch has been deprecated**

Chrome has a command line switch for this:

```
chrome.exe --disable-web-security
```

You can view a full list (as of when it was posted!) of command line options for chrome [here](http://yuridejager.wordpress.com/2009/03/10/chromium-chrome-command-line-switches/).

Comment: how to do this programatically?

Comment: I am not 100% sure but  Pragmatically its not possible. logically, by writing above line inside chrome we are disabling a security feature. The feature is only for disabling   the particular actions occurring from programming side. That's the reason I strongly believe. pragmatically its not possible.

Comment: This option has been removed from Google Chrome, it is only available with Chrome version 21.

Comment: @OctavianDamiean It's still available on Chromium ~25, if needed.

Comment: This works perfectly fine in Chrome 37 OS X --> open "Google Chrome.app" --args --disable-web-security

Answer (score 2):

You can install chrome plugins which enable cross-origin resource sharing .

I use [this](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/allow-control-allow-origi/nlfbmbojpeacfghkpbjhddihlkkiljbi) .

Comment: Thanks, I used all the other methods and they worked for awhile but the latest version of Chrome seems to block them. this works.