# KendoUI Autocomplete not working in firefox

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

My KendoUI Autocomplete example works in Chrome but not in Firefox.

I am able to type in a town name e.g. "watford" and get a result displayed in chrome.

Using FireBug, I can see that I am returning valid JSON result, but get a 'TypeError: e is undefined' error message.

http://jsfiddle.net/franH/znkV3/14/

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {

transition: 'slide'
});

$(document).ready(function() {
$("#autoComplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 7,
    dataTextField: "title",
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Select town...",
    animation: {
        open: {
            effects: "fadeIn",
            duration: 2000,
            show: true
        }
    },

    close: function(e) {
        var str1 = "Dropdown Item Selected:" + " " + e.item;
        alert(str1);
    },
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON",
                data: {
                    q: function() {
                        return $("#autoComplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
                    },
                    maxRows: 10,
                    username: "pete"

                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "geonames"
        }
    }),
    change: function() {
        this.dataSource.read();
    }
    })
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The only problem I see is that there is no such thing as `e.item` for the `close` event. Use the value method to get the value of the autocomplete.

Answer (score 1):

Hello you are requesting **json** from another domein which is not allowed by the [Same origin policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy). However by default [Chrome does not care about this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2600574/crossdomain-settings-in-google-chrome) and this is why it still works.

Since you cannot force Users to change their browsers settings I would suggest you to search for a [jsonp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP) endpoint or another service which supports it.

Answer (score 0):

Got it working in FireFox by adding the line

```
datatype: "jsonp",
```

Updated the example fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/franH/znkV3/15/

```
var app = new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, {
  transition: 'slide'
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#autoComplete").kendoAutoComplete({
    minLength: 7,
    dataTextField: "title",
    filter: "contains",
    placeholder: "Select town...",
    animation: {
        open: {
            effects: "fadeIn",
            duration: 2000,
            show: true
        }
    },

    close: function(e) {
        var str1 = "Dropdown Item Selected:" + " " + e.item;
        alert(str1);
    },
    dataSource: new kendo.data.DataSource({
        transport: {
            read: {
                url: "http://api.geonames.org/wikipediaSearchJSON",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                data: {
                    q: function() {
                        return $("#autoComplete").data("kendoAutoComplete").value();
                    },
                    maxRows: 10,
                    username: "pete"

                }
            }
        },
        schema: {
            data: "geonames"
        }
    }),
    change: function() {
        this.dataSource.read();
    }
  })
});
```